# Theory of real numbers is decidable but Peano arithmetic is undecidable?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, incompleteness, decidability

How can the theory of real numbers be decidable while Peano arithmetic is not? Why can't Godel numbering be used to demonstrate a true but unprovable sentence given that the natural numbers that are needed to construct such a sentence are subset of the real numbers, so *a fortiori*, from the stronger reason that PA is undecidable, the theory of real numbers must be as well. But that apparently isn't true and I'm wondering - why not?

Comment: This is a very natural and excellent question! However, it has been asked here before (see the linked duplicate). If there are points about the answers to the linked question that remain unclear, you can edit this question to focus on them (+ clarification of what remains unclear) and it will be reopened. One key point I'll make here is that the idea of a "genealogy" of mathematical structures, with e.g. the naturals preceding the reals, is **not** a rigorous mathematical result which has bearing on technical issues.

Comment: Meanwhile, a good exercise you can do on your own is try to find a way to "code" pairs of real numbers by individual real numbers using only the field structure. This **is** possible (in many ways) in the natural numbers, but **is not** possible in $\mathbb{R}$, and coming to grips with this is a key first step towards understanding how $(\mathbb{R};+,\times)$ can be "model-theoretically tamer" than $(\mathbb{N};+,\times)$.

Comment: I don't understand the downvotes. This was a duplicate, but it's **not** a bad question or poorly asked. What gives?

Comment: Thank you @NoahSchweber! I'm guessing something simple like encoding a pair of reals $(x,y) $ with a real $z$ that is defined by setting $z_{2*i} := x_i$ when i is odd and otherwise set it to $y_i$ is not possible using only the field structure of $R$, is that right?